# Merging 2 raster images into one plot using the `raster` package

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I would like to add an enlarged portion of my map to the original map and have as the final product, one map that shows both the original map, and also the enlarged/zoomed portion. Using the `meuse` dataset as an example:

```
library(sp)
library(lattice) 
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y
gridded(meuse)<-TRUE
rasters.m<-list()
for (i in 1:12){
rasDF <- raster(meuse, layer=i)
rasters.m[[i]]<-rasDF
}
stack.sp<-stack(rasters.m)
 plot(stack.sp) # gives a gridded view of the stacked rasters. But now I would like to zoom in..
 zoom.ent<-zoom(stack.sp,1) #  The zoomed in portion appears as a new window, with the boundaries of the zoomed area highlighted in red on the original map.
```

I am not sure if there is a command in the `raster` or `rasterVIS` packages that would allow one to add the zoomed in part of the raster onto the original map. I have tried the `par` function but that doesn't work. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Possible alternative: something along the lines of `plot(0:1,t='n') #set up window;raster(bigplot,0,0,1,1);raster(littleplot,0,0,.2,.2)` ?

Comment: Thanks Carl for the suggestion, but not sure what structure 'bigplot' and 'littleplot' would be.. Would it be possible to elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I was thinking of an arbitrary "main" plot that contained your full image, and the "littleplot" would be whatever `raster` object you wanted to insert over the full plot.  Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less the same question [you asked here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120623/inserting-a-zoomed-in-plot-with-a-full-scale-plot-in-the-sp-package-in-r). For `Raster*` objects you have to use the `shift` function. The result can be combined with the `+.trellis` function of the `latticeExtra` package:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

rZoom <- crop(r, extent(180000,  181000, 330000, 331500))

displaced <- shift(rZoom, x = -1200, y = 2000)

levelplot(r) + levelplot(displaced)
```

[image: shift]

Comment: Thanks for the rasterVis package. Very helpful thus far. But I noticed that the sampled area is the same size as the rest of the image. I was looking for a function within `rasterVis` documentation that would allow to change the scale, to allow the sampled area to be magnified. I will continue trying different options. But thanks again

Comment: @user2507608 What do you mean with "the same size"? `rZoom` has 950 cells (38x25) while `r` has 9200 (115x80).